# What version of Ruby to use in Why's (Poignant) Guide to Ruby

Tags: ruby

I've been following Why's (Poignant) Guide to Ruby for the past few days, and I've noticed some problems with running his examples.

I'm at a crossroads now as to whether I've made a few typos that I can't seem to catch, or that my Ruby version is incompatible.

I'm running Ruby 1.8.6 (Win32), and I noticed in Chapter 5 in the irb prompt mention of Ruby 1.8.3.

Before I drive myself mad; is it just me or do I need to downgrade to 1.8.3?

Along those lines, how hard would it be to port the code up to 1.8.6 in the event that they aren't compatible?

Comment: If you paste the code you have trouble with, we could help you to see if it's a compatibility issue or a typo.

Comment: I found out what the problem was, actually. In Chapter 6 you create Dwemthy's Array, and then 'require' it into irb. I didn't realize at the time that regular variables don't make it through a 'require'.

The quick way around it that I found was to capitalize the first letter of the variable. eg. dwary => Dwary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty certain you will be fine. I have never really worried about point releases as long as the "branch" version remained the same. I think you will find that 99.9%, if not 100%, of the things you are working through in why's guide will still work no matter which version of Ruby 1.8 you use.

Here is a snippet from the Ruby 1.8 [branch policy](http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/wiki/2/BranchPolicy) from the [ruby-lang issue tracker site](http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/projects/show/ruby-18):

> The 1.8 branch, or in general, a
>   "stable" branch is developed and
>   maintained for most casual use by
>   average ruby programmers. Besides
>   fixes for security problems and
>   run-time bugs, there can be
>   performance improvements, feature
>   enhancements and library updates made
>   on the branch. Those kinds of
>   aggressive changes may occur, however,
>   only on condition that backward
>   compatibilities and run-time
>   stabilities are retained to a high
>   degree.

...

> Committers are allowed to make a
>   commit on a stable branch without
>   explicit approval from the branch
>   manager, as long as it does not break
>   any backward compatibilities, that is,
>   it does not delete or change any
>   existing features.
>
> A list of exceptions is as follows. A
>   commit may break backward
>   compatibilities only when all of the
>   following conditions are met:
>
> - It only affects: 1) behaviors which
>     contradicts with the document, 
>     2) internal, unpublicized interface, 3)
>     undocumented features, 4) undefined
>     behaviors, or 5) presumable misuses.
> - The new behavior will not change again
>     in nor contradict with the next major
>     version series of Ruby.
> - If it is
>     assumed that it may silently affect
>     existing code in a subtle way,
>     sufficient information and/or a
>     support tool must be supplied with to
>     help users fix their existing code.
> - It is well considered and reviewed in
>     public and approved by the branch
>     manager.
> - It is well documented and
>     announced in ChangeLog and NEWS as
>     soon as it goes in.

Answer (score 1):

1.8.6 shouldn't pose any problems. Poignant Guide readers haven't been using 1.8.3 for many years, and _why was still writing the guide when he was using much later versions. So I don't believe there are any compatibility problems.